# Why getting error when request docusign JWT token

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I need to get JWT token from Docusign and send email to get signature.

I used docusign provided repo code sample and it doesn't work.
github link https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt

```
await dsApi.requestJWTUserToken(dsConfig.clientId,
      dsConfig.impersonatedUserGuid, scopes, dsConfig.privateKey,
      jwtLifeSec)
```

error > Error: error:0908F070:PEM routines:get_header_and_data:short header

what I missed get to work this project.

Comment: they have bad documentation and outdated (full of errors) code examples

Comment: Hello @evansgambit, can you be a bit more specific about which errors do you see? Would be happy to work to fix them.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by removing extra spaces on every line starts, after each new line characters.

By default, my IDE was adding two spaces for identation at the begining of every line.

```js
  privateKey: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA8um2ZIdO5UdLBBJ6vKORodORRz6+TI+5JpJRFszojzZAwHgF
^^
```

The javascript `` template syntax is considering every characters from the line start.

Comment: Alternate idea: strip the whitespace in code: `privateKey: \`-----BEGIN [redacted]\`.replace(/\n\s+/g, "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the following:
1. You generated Integration Key in the Sandbox environment
2. You have stored your private RSA Key and it's properly formed.
3. The urls you use are for Sandbox not production (demo or -d)

The error above is misleading/confusing but something is wrong with the authentication call, often it's the key that's bad.

Comment: I just downloaded official repository project and followed all instructions properly. Is there any code or project sample for get authentication key without putting temporary generated key.

Comment: did you create an RSA Private key? and make sure you used it correctly in your code?

Comment: yes I did that. I did exactly what document say. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I created separate .pem file and put the secret key. Then read file form the code. Its worked for me.